# How to authenticate logins to Ericsson(IPSO) routers without password from shell server

Tags: router, ssh, authentication

I am very new at networks. I am attempting to automate the health check process of a system network from the main server being a shell OS.

I have been successful for some network nodes which are also running the shell OS by using the `SSH authentication rsa key pairs`.

However, the ericsson routers are running on the IPOS Ericsson OS. I tried to do the same SSH authentication using `bash` installed in the router, by adding the rsa public key into `~/.ssh/known_hosts`, but it still prompts for password for access.

Are there any ways i can access the ericsson router without password prompts? perhaps an authentication key? Maybe even ansible?

I am not sure what other information i should provide, so i will edit as i go along.
*Edit 1. The OS version is IPOS-17.3.1.0.160p15. It is not IOS.

Comment: Wich version of IOS are you using? Public key ssh authentication only works since IOS 15.0.

Comment: Hi! thank you for responding. I checked and it says IPOS-17.3.1.0.160p15-

Comment: Hm - as far as I know, we haven't seen anything above IOS-XE _16.8_ in the field.  What kind of device is that? Can you please provide the output of "show version" and/or "show inventory" (you might want to mask the serial numbers in the latter).

Comment: It is this:    Ericsson IPOS Version IPOS-17.3.1.0.160p15-Release
Copyright (C) 1998-2018, Ericsson AB. All rights reserved.
Operating System version is Linux 3.14.25-00331-ga8abfa8
System Bootstrap version is OpenFirmware  3.0.2.53  PRODUCTION RELEASE
Installed minikernel version is v3.14.25-00292-gddbb3fa
Router Up Time -  31 days, 39 minutes 31 seconds.      However, i couldn't find any documentation of his Ericsson router. The most similar one I found is Cisco. I figured i could learn from some techniques from this brand of router. I seek your understanding

Comment: Please edit your question and title to show the correct vendor and OS platform.

Comment: A quick google search let me think that Ericsson IPOS is quite far away from IOS. Even if the TechSpec of Ericsson and Cisco Route are comparable, doesn't mean that the OS and configuration will also do.

Comment: alright i've changed the question to better suit my situation

Comment: Have you tried the standard ssh `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file?

Comment: yes. In my case, it is stored in ~/.ssh/known_hosts. All the pub keys are in there. However, when i try to log in, it still prompts for password. To access the ~/.ssh/known_hosts, i had to "start shell" and use bash installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank to the commentators for their help: I have realised the mistake. I needed to first create the "authorized_keys" file in the ~/.ssh/ directory manually. I mistook the "known_hosts" file as the "authorized keys" when they are in fact unrelated.

Such a code `$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh username@server.address.com 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'` wouldn't work for me because the destination server is not running bash by default.

( Also, by some odd turnout of events, the vi editor produced an error "(insert) VISUALS" in the ericsson server, which i have never faced before in Linux. It prevents whatever that is in the clipboard from pasting into the file. So i had to force the rsa pub key by doing `$echo '<here is the rsa pub key>' >> authorized_keys`. For this oddity i haven't found out what is causing it yet. )

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.